# ETH Recived... but Balance = 0 on etherscan and MetaMask

Tags: metamask, etherscan

I folks. I recived 3 days ago 0.00741522 ETH, but until now my account's balance is 0 ETH and I don't know why. I share the etherscan capture:
[image]

Thanks people :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your wallet has been compromised. The eth was immediately sent out to another address. check etherscan for more details

Comment: Yes... I see now what the sending ETH + txfee = recived ETH .... crap. Thanks clinton-arf